# How to let PowerBI consume my restful service which is secured by access token?

Tags: api, rest, powerbi

We have a RESTful API which allows multiple customers to retrieve data from. But before that, customers need to authenticate with their credentials and get the access token to access the API.  The access token will be expired every 30 minutes, so customers need to re-login again to get a new access token.

The RESTful service will determine by the access token to return customer's data.

We want to use PowerBI to present customers' data.

My question is how to integrate our authentication process with PowerBI? what type of dataset do we need to create?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let
Query2 = let

url="http://api.XXXXX.com/api/1.0/authentication/login",
body = "{
          ""userName"":""XXX"", 
          ""password"":""XXXX"" 
        }",

jsonResult = Json.Document(Web.Contents(url,[Headers =[#"Content-Type"="application/json"],Content = Text.ToBinary(body) , Timeout=#duration(0,2,0,0)])), 
token = jsonResult[accessToken],
location_url = "http://api.XXXXX.com/api/1.0/cts/sites",
sites = Json.Document(Web.Contents(location_url,[Headers =[Accept="application/json", Authorization=token]]))
```

in
    sites[result]